# convert the audio into no overlapping frames in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio-processing

This is code i wrote for convert audio into frames after the Dct transformation 
first i haveto converted the audio samples into Dct frequencies
second  i have to divide into segments
then divide each segments into four frames 
 below code is i tried but in for loop it is not working or giving wrong values
i need non overlapping frames
anyone know about this?
can someone help me?

```
%Original Audio Signal Dct Conversion

%Original_audio input
[filename , pathname] = uigetfile({'*.wav'}, 'Select File');
fullpathname = strcat (pathname, filename);
[original_audio, Fs] = audioread(fullpathname);

%Do DCT Transform for Original Audio
original_audio_dct = abs(dct(original_audio));
audio_length=length(original_audio_dct);

%%
%original Audio Signal segmentation

fs=44100;
segment_duration = 0.01;
segment_length = segment_duration*fs;
no_segment = floor(audio_length/segment_length);

 for k = 1 : no_segment 
   for j = 1:no_segment
   segment(j)= original_audio_dct((k-1)*segment_length+1:k*segment_length);

     for n = 1:4
         frame_length = floor(length(segment)/4);
         frame = segment(frame_length+1:2*frame_length);
        max_val = max(frame);


     end
    end
  end
```